# Vaadin Spring Boot: "Cannot access state in VaadinSession or UI without locking the session" when multiple users access UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a vaadin flow (13) application with spring boot. I have a VerticalLayout, annotated with `@UIScope` with multiple sub-layouts. The sub layouts are annotated with `@Scope("prototype")` and created via `ctx.getBean(SubUI.class, ...)`. Depending on selections and button clicks on the parent UI (VerticalLayout), the sub layouts are added or removed.

That all works fine as long as I use the application alone (that's the reason why I found the error right now, after delivering the application to my customer for acceptantce test). They tested with multiple users. As long as one user works with the appliaction, everything works but as soon as a second user enters the UI (VerticalLayout), the following exception is thrown:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access state in VaadinSession or UI without locking the session.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    ...
```

I tried different annotations for my parent layout (@UIScope, @Scope("prototype"), @VaadinSessionScope) but non solves my error.

I googled about the problem and found some threads, but none of them helped me to solve my problem. I am not really sure if the problem is caused by the scoping of my UIs/layouts or maybe by the data binding. In my sub layouts, data is bound using `Binder<MyEntity> binder = new Binder<>(MyEntity.class);` and `binder.forField(xxx).bind(MyEntity::getXY,MyEntity::setXY);`.

Can someone maybe explain me, what my problem is? I would be really happy, because I need to deliver a fixed version for my customers test.

Kind regards

Comment: Could you share the full stacktrace and also try running your application with assertions enabled (`-ea` as a JVM parameter) to see if that gives any additional information?

Answer (score 9):

You have some logic in your app that attempts to modify UI state, components etc. from a *background* thread.  That should be done guarded by locking. So you need to encapsulate the logic in your view that is called from background method with

```
getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.access(() -> {
    ...
}));
```

Also, `Server Push` should be enabled.

Documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/server-push

Comment: Thank you! So what exactly do I have to encapsulate? The procedures where the UI is modified? I have a procedure called `editDataBasedOnSelection()` that adds the required sub views. This procedure is called in a buttons ClickListener. So is it right to encapsulate the call of the procedure inside the Click Listener like `myButton.addClickListener(event -> {<your encapsulation code here>editDataBasedOnSelection()<end encapsulation>});`?

Comment: And do you maybe have a link for me to a documentation explaining the backgrounds and the whole concept in detail? I would really like to better understand what I am doing here. Anyway, I will try to get it to work with your hint this evening.

Comment: @tigu within a clicklistener you don't have to encapsulate modifications to the ui. You only have to do this when you manually start your own `Thread`. Every modification to the ui that you do from within that "background" Thread must be encapsulated. See also: [Asynchronous Updates](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html). Do you start your own Thread somewhere in your view?

Comment: @kscherrer, no, I am not starting any own Threads. But with the hints of you and @Tata Lund I started to debug it again today and found a solution. I had added / removed an autowired component that was annotated `@UIScope`. I changed it to `@Scope("prototype")` and fetched it with `ctx.getBean()`. Now my UI works even with multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I was facing a similar issue with the exact same error message in a Vaadin-based MVC application (not using Spring MVC in addition to what Vaadin provides ootb). The root cause was the way the application was architected: The controllers in the MVC application were constructed as stateless singletons, similar to Spring MVC, which is fine.

However, the views were instantiated and registered not per user/session, but globally. This worked alright during local development when only one user was accessing the application, but failed as soon as more than one user was logged in, because the Vaadin application tried to access the same view instance from different sessions. This lead to the error stated by the OP.

The solution then was to disentangle the MVC architecture and make sure that different view instances get created per user session.